# Installing Android plugin with Eclipse (Indigo SR 1)

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

[image]Friends,
        I am trying to install Android plugin with Eclipse(Version: Indigo Service Release 1) in my machine(Linux Ubuntu 64 bit). My network uses proxy authentication so I went to Eclipse->windows->preferences->General->Network connection->Entered my credentials(for http & https).

And to install android -- Eclipse->Help->Install new software->Added the URL(Andriod - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) and then clicked next.But it said some more plugins are missing.So I tried to update the eclipse.But when I tried to update the eclipse through the following URL(Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios) it gives the following exception :
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/content.xml
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/content.xml
Proxy auth required
Please help me with this..

FYI: I am entering the valid credentials,I can visit sites through that same credentials with my browser.

Answer (score 0):

hmm
Eclipse->Help->Install new software->drop down to all available sites  and select sdk install it and then move on to android http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: what do you mean by "select SDK"?